# Binding to Title property of page not working on UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I'm having an issue binding to the `Title` property of my `TabbedPage`. Here is my view code:

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="App.View.Pages.MyPage"
         xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:App.View.Page; assembly=App.View.Pages"
         Title="{Binding Title}">
```

and my ViewModel code:

```
private string _Title;
public string Title
{
    get { return _Title; }
    set { Set(() => Title, ref _Title, value); }
}
```

I use this code to change the title from my ViewModel:

```
Title = "My new title"
```

It works on Android, but not on UWP. On Android, the title of this page is changed in real time, when I execute this code on UWP, I must "reload" page by switching to another page and then returning to this one. Does anyone know why this is happening or how to fix it?

EDIT: I switch the title when the user chooses an item from a `DialogBox`.

Comment: Try this: `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {Title = "My new title";});` and make sure you have the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented in your ViewModel.

Comment: On Android it's ok, on UWP no change...

Comment: I use MVVM light, so the INotifyPropertyChanged interface is implemented

Comment: I found this problem on Xamarin's bugzilla:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=56164

So... I have to wait to version 2.3.5... Or how to I can fix it manually?

Comment: Great find! The easiest would be to install the pre-release nuget for now, but it may be a bit unstable, but you could try. Just check the 'show prereleases' box in the add nuget package screen

Comment: Thank you! I have not seen this function in nuget ;) It's working with new version of Xamarin :)